# Who can sign my certificate authority?

Tags: windows-10, ssl, certificate, trusted-root-certificates, trusted-root-ca

I am new to the certificate business and from what I understand if a root certificate is installed in Windows 10, any certificates that are signed by that root, they are automatically trusted.

So this is what I want my chain to look like:

- Root (All purposes)

  - Apps (Code signing purpose)

    - One certificate for each app.
  - Websites (SSL)

    - One certificate for each website.

What I though is that my app installer, before actually installing the app, it could install the root certificate and the two intermediate certificate. Then it could also install the certificate (signed by the apps cert) and then install the app. But obviously this won't work because my installer will be downloaded from my website and the website won't be trusted until the installer runs.

What I was wondering, would it be possible to get my root signed by an already trusted ca (Digi Sign, Let's Encrypt, etc.). If this is possible, then would all of my certificates (Root, Intermediates, Individual Apps/Websites) be auto trusted?

If so, what type of signing or certificate will I need from a CA? Could someone please suggest a CA? I can't find one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, another CA could cross-sign yours. But only if you're *already* an established CA in general, as the other CA's reputation rests on them only issuing certificates that satisfy the industry-required validation rules and more – and that extends to all CAs that they've cross-signed.

For example, the "Let's Encrypt" intermediates were cross-signed by IdenTrust for the initial few years, until ISRG's own root CA certificates became widespread enough. (Yes, "Let's Encrypt" is not a root CA – ISRG is.)

So it's possible, but if you're just running the operation from your garage, that's *very* unlikely to happen. I'd say it's actually less likely than just getting your root CA directly accepted in the Windows "trusted CA" list.

As another option, if a customer needs a *large* amount of certificates, many CAs offer to issue an intermediate just for that customer. In the past, this used to mean you'd just get the private key and everything; nowadays it's a bit frowned upon (due to several cases of such intermediates finding their way into "SSL inspection" hardware and being used to spoof certificates on the whim of some CEO).

So while it's still possible to buy an intermediate CA cert, now you only get remote API access to a certificate that's still managed by the original CA – your company's name shows up in the hierarchy but you're still subject to validation rules.

In other words, CAs tend to avoid doing what you're asking for, and I suspect it's precisely so that their certificates *would not* be used for purposes like yours. Nobody likes a random program on their computer issuing bogus certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a good read of Wikipedia
[Public key certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate)
before continuing, since your post show some lack of understanding of the
basic concepts:

- Root certificates are usually reserved for Certificate Authorities
- You will need two kinds of certificates issued by a known
  Certificate Authority: TLS/SSL server certificate for your
  website(s) and Code signing certificate for your apps.
  You may use the same certificate for several websites/programs.
- You do not need to install your certificates, this will be automatic
  when they are validated by their Certificate Authority.

There is an enormous amount of information about certificates that is
available on the internet. All you need to do is search and read.

Answer (score 0):

> What I though is that my app installer, before actually installing the app, it could install the root certificate and the two intermediate certificate.

How you install a certificate entirely depends on the operating system you are dealing with.  For instance, an iOS application cannot be installed on the device unless Apple signs it. Therefore, you won't be able install an iOS application signed by your own certificate on any iOS device.  Likewise, Windows will allow you to install any certificate you want to the certificate store manually.  This will allow the end user to access an encrypted HTTPS session that is using a self-signed certificate.  However, only validated code signing certificates can be used to publish UWP applications to the Windows Store.

You can self-sign your own code signing certificate but the end user would have to install the certificate to the certificate store on the device, otherwise, Windows would complain and indicate that there was problem with the certificate used to sign the application.

> Then it could also install the certificate (signed by the apps cert) and then install the app. But obviously this won't work because my installer will be downloaded from my website and the website won't be trusted until the installer runs.

This is the reason you will have to simply purchase the certificate used to sign the installer.  **However, applications that install certificates to a user's certificate store, so it can additional code is typically referred to as malware.** An iOS device cannot install a certificate to an iOS device.

> What I was wondering, would it be possible to get my root signed by an already trusted ca (Digi Sign, Let's Encrypt, etc.). If this is possible, then would all of my certificates (Root, Intermediates, Individual Apps/Websites) be auto trusted?

**This will never happen.**  If a Root CA gave you a certificate, you could use it to create additional certificates, and then you wouldn't need them to create additional certificates. Additionally, by virtue of signing that first certificate, they would also be signing any certificate that was signed by the certificate they originally provided.  **This means the owner of that certificate, you could literally create any certificate you wanted, and the only way to NOT trust the certificate you create would be to revoke the Root CA certificate used to originally sign it**  The revocation of a Root CA is serious business since any certificate signed by it would also no longer be trusted.

This, of course, is because the entire trust path is entirely reliant on that first certificate.  The only reason a Root CA certificate should be revoked is if there is evidence it's being to sign certificates that ultimately have a connection to malware (or perhaps it was accidentally compromised).  **There is a reason Root CA are good for 15 years.**

**In the past, Google, Microsoft, Apple, and Mozilla have threatened to revoke a Root CA certificate due to bad business practices that resulted in that Root CA certificate being used to sign malware.**

> If so, what type of signing or certificate will I need from a CA? Could someone please suggest a CA? I can't find one.

You need individual certificates for any website you might have and a certificate for any platform to sign your application code.  What is required for that entirely depends on the platform.  Windows, Apple, and Google all have different requirements to published digital signed code.  In some cases it's not even required to sign code in other words unsigned code cannot be ran.